# 404 error for popup modal form in django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am getting 404 error for a popup form, I am trying to open on clicking a text link.

accounts/urls.py

```
url("_/user-popup/(?P<key>\w+)/$", views.user_popup_form, name="user_popup_form"),
url("_/user-popup/(?P<key>\w+)/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$", views.user_popup_form, name="user_popup_form"),
```

accounts/views.py--

```
POPUP_FORMS = {
    "profile": {
        "form": forms.UserProfileForm,
        "templates": {
            ".nav_user_name": "user/nav_user_name.html",
            ".profile_info": "user/profile_info.html",
            ".about_text": "user/about_text.html",
        }
    }
    # etc.
}

def user_popup_form(request, key, pk=None):
    """
    Handle any form with a "user" field pointing back
    to the logged in user. Otherwise return a
    HttpResponseForbidden response.
    """

    if (not request.user.is_authenticated) or (not key in POPUP_FORMS):
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()

    content = {}

    instance = POPUP_FORMS[key]['form']._meta.model.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if pk:
        instance = instance.filter(pk=Hasher.decode(pk)[0])
    else:
        if not isinstance(POPUP_FORMS[key]['form']._meta.model.user.field, OneToOneField):
            instance = None
    instance = instance[0] if instance else None

    if request.POST or request.FILES:
        form = POPUP_FORMS[key]['form'](request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance, initial={"user": request.user})
        success = form.is_valid()
        if success:
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            try:
                instance.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                success = False
                form.errors['__all__'] = ["Form data not unique - have you already added one of these?"]
            except Exception as e:
                success = False
                form.errors['__all__'] = [e]
            else:
                models.User.objects.update()
                request.user.refresh_from_db()
                POPUP_FORMS[key]['form']._meta.model.objects.update()
                for name, template in POPUP_FORMS[key]['templates'].items():
                    content[name] = render_to_string(template, {"profile": request.user.profile}, request)

    else:
        form = POPUP_FORMS[key]['form'](instance=instance, initial={"user": request.user})
        success = False

    return JsonResponse({
        "form": Template("{% load crispy_forms_tags %}{% crispy form %}").render(Context({"request": request, "form": form})),
        "title": capfirst(key),
        "success": success,
        "content": content
    })
```

site.js under static folder

```
$("body").on("click tap", "a[data-user-popup]", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        button.attr("disabled", true).find("span.fa").addClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
        var url = "/_/user-popup/" + button.attr("data-user-popup") + "/";
        if(button.attr("data-item-id")) {
            url += button.attr("data-item-id") + "/";
        }
        alert(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET"
        }).always(function() {
            button.attr("disabled", false).find("span.fa").removeClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
        }).done(function(data) {
            bootbox.hideAll();
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: data.title,
                message: data.form,
                html: true,
                buttons: {
                    "save": {
                        className: "btn-success",
                        label: "Save",
                        callback: function() {
                            var saveButton = $(".bootbox-footer .btn-success");
                            saveButton.attr("disabled", true).find("span.fa").addClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
                            $.ajax({
                                url: url,
                                type: "POST",
                                data: $(".bootbox-body form").serialize(),
                                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": Refocus.csrfToken }
                            }).always(function() {
                                saveButton.attr("disabled", false).find("span.fa").removeClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                if(data.success) {
                                    bootbox.hideAll();
                                    for (var key in data.content) {
                                        $(key).html(data.content[key]);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $(".bootbox-body").html(data.form);
                                    $(".modal").scrollTop(0);
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    "cancel": {
                        className: "btn-default",
                        label: "Cancel"
                    }
                }
            }).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $(".modal.fade.in .modal-body input, .modal.fade.in .modal-body textarea, .modal.fade.in .modal-body select").first().select().focus();
            });
            $(".modal.fade.in").scrollTop(0);
        });
    });
```

The user profile url is

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/user` and the code to get a pop up is

```
{% if profile.pk == request.user.profile.pk %}
<p><a data-user-popup="profile" href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Edit profile</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error if  `DEBUG = True` is in you settings.py?

Comment: Debug is set to true in settings.py. I get the error in terminal. It's 
`Not Found: /user_popup/profile
[28/Aug/2017 22:59:09] "GET /user_popup/profile HTTP/1.1" 404 2187`

Comment: Check the full response in chrome dev-tools network tab.

Comment: The js code above seems to always add a trailing slash, but do check your `APPEND_SLASH` setting, as that error message suggests you're asking for an url that is not on the url file (for a lack of trailing slash).

Comment: I checked in chrome response and I don't know why it is looking for that url i n `project.urls` whereas it should look at `project.appname.urls`. I think popup might work from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user` but not from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/user`.

Comment: I don't have `APPEND_SLASH` setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153071/discussion-between-chicocvenancio-and-prithviraj-mitra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your app urls.py file in the project urls.py file([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    (...)
    url(r'_/', include('account.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I did that. Still getting 404.